# How to make background fit text in 2 column layout

Tags: html, css

This sample below creates grey background which fills all page width, but I want this background to cover only text and nothing else. How can I do this? 
Code is taken from this page: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_two_columns

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[This is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIRmD.png)

Comment: you want same as in w3school example right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed by your code,now maybe this is what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" >
    <h2 style="background-color:#aaa;display:inline-block;">Column 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2 style="background-color:#bbb;display:inline-block;">Column 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now it is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope your query is resolved.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" >
    <span style="background-color:#aaa;">Column 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span style="background-color:#bbb;">Column 2</span>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```